# Is there a basic expiring Map in Dart?

Tags: dart

Is there an expiring map in dart ? I'm looking for something similar to PassiveExpiringMap in Apache common.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a package for this. However, in case anyone is just looking for a quick snippet to lazily copy and paste like I did, here's a start you can taylor to your needs:

```dart
class ExpiringMap {
  final Map<dynamic, dynamic> _map = {};

  Object operator [](Object key) => _map[key];

  void operator []=(Object key, Object value) {
    _map[key] = value;
    Future.delayed(Duration(minutes: 1), () => _map.remove(key));
  }
}
```

Comment: Some people may want to make this a generic ExpiringMap<K, V> and instead of a Future.delayed, use a map of timers and reschedule the expiration on access. But that might be overkill depending on use case. This code gets the job done!